# Difference between dates, rounded result to nearest minute

Tags: javascript, reactjs, datetime, momentjs

The difference between dates wants to round to the nearest minute.
Round `date1`,`date2` down or up. The returned result is already rounded up to the full minute. I can modify `date1`,`date2`. Do not modify the result already returned

`date2- date1`

Code here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-azau4g

Example:

**First step**

```
this.state = {
  date1: "2019-06-29 21:25:38+00",
  date2: "2019-06-29T21:25:40.000+00:00"
}

round = (item) => {
  var m = moment(item);

  var roundUp = (m.second() || m.millisecond() ? m.add(1, 'minute').startOf('minute') : m.startOf('minute')).toISOString();
  return roundUp;
}

differentTime = {
    date1: this.state.date1.toISOString(),  
    date2: this.round(this.state.date2)   //return "2019-06-29T21:26:00.000+00:00"
}
```

**Second step**

Expected effect:

`data2` - `data1` = 1 min

---

**Example 2**

```
 this.state = {
      date1: "2019-06-29 21:25:01+00",
      date2: "2019-06-29T21:27:20.000+00:00"
    }



 differentTime2 = {
        date1: this.state.date1.toISOString(), 
        date2: this.round(this.state.date2)   //return "2019-06-29T21:28:00.000+00:00"
    }
```

Expecting effect:

`date2` - `date1` = 3 min

Comment: Both your code samples give `this.state.date1.toISOString is not a function`.  Also you can't subtract strings.  Please show the *exact* code that you are working with.  Also, your `round` function sometimes returns a string and sometime returns a `Moment` object.

Comment: I paste simple code

Comment: What _is_ the question?

Comment: @Styx   Is it possible to achieve such a result by modifying only date1,` date2`? and not the result? for example date2 - date1 = result. Result can not be modified. You can modify only date2, date1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you want a function that subtracts one date from another and round the difference to the nearest minute.

This can't be done with a single argument like the `round` function in your question; you need a function that takes both dates as arguments.

I'm not too familiar with moment, but here's a function that should work for built-in Dates.

EDIT: Per OP's comments, I've updated the function to modify `d2` rather than returning diff.

```js
    MS_IN_MINUTES = 60000;

    roundAway = (d1, d2) => {
      let diff = d2 - d1 // Difference in milliseconds (+ or -)
      let positive = diff > 0 // Whether we should add later
      diff = Math.abs(diff) // Difference in milliseconds (+)
      diff = diff / MS_IN_MINUTES // Difference in minutes (not rounded)
      diff = Math.ceil(diff) // Difference in minutes (rounded up)
      let roundedAway = d1.getTime()
      if (positive) {
          roundedAway += diff * MS_IN_MINUTES
      }
      else {
          roundedAway -= diff * MS_IN_MINUTES
      }
      d2.setTime(roundedAway)
    }
    
    let date1 = new Date("2019-06-29 21:25:38+00");
    console.log('date1:', date1)

    let date2 = new Date("2019-06-29T21:25:40.000+00:00");
    console.log('date2:', date2)

    let date3 = new Date("2019-06-29T21:24:36.000+00:00");
    console.log('date3:', date3)

    console.log('Unchanged date1:', date1);

    roundAway(date1, date2);
    console.log('Rounded date2:', date2);

    roundAway(date1, date3);
    console.log('Rounded date3:', date3);
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Is it possible to achieve such a result by modifying only `date1`,` date2`? and not the result? for example date2 - date1 = result. Result can not be modified. You can modify only date2, date1

Comment: Hmm so given d1 and d2 where `d1 - d2 = diff`, you want a function to modify d2 so that it's equal to d1 +/- X minutes, where X is diff rounded up to the nearest minute?

I'm sure that's possible (especially with the `moment` methods you showed), but it's going to be much uglier than code that operates on diff.

Comment: I can only send to 'api' date1, date2; I can not send a difference

Comment: Okay, I've updated my code snippet to modify d2 instead of returning diff. It should do what I described in my previous comment.

Answer (score 0):

This might help you round a date to the nearest minute:

```
const date = moment("2019-06-29T21:59:59.000+00:00");
const seconds = date.seconds();
date.add(seconds > 0 && 60 - seconds, 's');
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use the `diff` method to get the number of milliseconds, convert it to minutes and then ceil the result

```
import moment from 'moment';

let date1 = moment("2019-06-29 21:25:38+00");
console.log(date1)

let date2 = moment("2019-06-29T21:25:40.000+00:00");
console.log(date2)

// get the difference between the moments
const diff = date2.diff(date1);
console.log(diff);

// convert to minutes and ceil
const diffInMinutes = Math.ceil(diff/60000);
console.log(diffInMinutes);
```